# Microsoft band get data real time without the use of a mobile

Tags: bluetooth, microsoft-band

I have purchased microsoft band. My scope is to use that device in order to track information such as steps and heart rate real time. I am wandering is there a way to get those data real time without 3rd device directly to a pc, using for example a bluetooth device? Is there a filesystem in order to store data in Band device? How can I store my data when for example I am outside and I dont having a mobile support?

Edit: I downloaded the sample code from the [site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44579). Now I am having problems running the project using either the device of the emulator. In both cases I am receiving bootstrapping device failed. Device not found. In case of the emulator I got the following error:

```
Error   2   Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Emulator 8.1 U1 qHD 5 inch' failed. Device cannot be found. The configuration data for this product is corrupt. Contact your support personnel.
Personalization.WindowsPhone
```

How can I pair the device with my app? I have already pair the device with pc using the microsoft sync app.

Edit2: I create a windows runtime app and I followed instruction from the [link](http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf) mentioned. I manage to found the paired device from the code. How can I read heart rate using the paired device?

My code is the following:

```
     IBandInfo[] bandsPaired = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
     IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(bandsPaired[0]);

      if (bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.GetCurrentUserConsent() != UserConsent.Granted)
      {

         await bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.RequestUserConsentAsync();
      }
```

What should I do to get the heart rate as a integer value? Is there a way to import the project to unity?

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed the Windows 8.1 SDKs.  What version of OS are you using? Can you successfully create a new (empty) Windows 8.1 application?

Comment: Basically I use the express version of visual studio that was the reason for my problems. Now I am having problems running the project using either the device of the emulator. In both cases I am receiving bootstrapping device failed. Device not found.

Comment: The phone emulator does not support Bluetooth, so you must run the application on a real (either Windows 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1) device.  You'll need to be more specific about the error your seeing (e.g. actual exception message and callstack) as I don't recognize that as a Band SDK error.

Comment: I have pair the device with my bluetooth I use the above code in a universal windows store app which track the paired device and I try to return useful information real time. My problem is how to get the information, if I can get it without the use of the mobile devide real time.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following; in order to stream data from the Band, you must first Bluetooth pair it to *a* device, whether a PC or a phone.  Once you've done that, then you can use the Band SDK in an application on that PC or phone to retrieve the data.  There is no way to stream data from the Band except through a Bluetooth connection from a device.

Comment: @PhilHoff--MSFT exactly. I have paired the device with my pc's bluetooth antenna.  I use this code  IBandInfo[] bandsPaired = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync(); to get the devices and I get a list with one device which is actually the band. What is going to be the second step in order to get the heart rate?

Answer (score 6):

For running and workouts you don't need a mobile. But if your ideia is use the Band indefinitely, for days, and then sync with a storage will not work.
The Microsoft Band is like a aggregate of sensors, not a device that works alone.

Comment: Basically I want to get real time heart rate data on the spot to a pc via a bluetooth communication without having a mobile device.  Can I do such thing?

Answer (score 5):

You can pair the Band directly to a Bluetooth-enabled (e.g. Windows) PC, then use the Band SDK to connect to the Band and stream real-time data from a Windows application.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to do so?

Comment: I have installed microsoft band sync application and I pair and sync the device with pc. How can I create a app to get real time data?

Comment: Start with a new Windows 8.1 (universal) application.  Then apply the Band SDK NuGet package to the project.  Then follow the instructions/samples from the Band SDK documentation:  http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf

Comment: I start a universal Apps a windows runtime compontent. I follow the instructions add proximity and the specification in the manifest. I tried to add the code mention in the link, however when I run my program it doesnt seem that it finds my device.

Comment: Do you simply get an empty collection of devices, or does the enumeration itself fail?  Make sure that the machine/phone running the application was the most recent device to be paired to the Band.  The Band will connect to only the last device it has been paired with.

Comment: I managed to pair the devicesmy issue is how to get the heart rate info.